# align logo with pagenumber in beamer

Tags: beamer

How can I align logo and page number at the same level? Now it seems logo on top of page number.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\logo{\makebox[1\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{Hello world}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Do you want to move the logo "downwards" so as to be at the same level with the frame number () or do you want to just move it to the right (as in the answer below) so the logo and the frame number are both aligned to the right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the logo to appear centered in the footline, you need to redefine the `footline` template as implemented by the `frame number` option (original code in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`) and to set the `sidebar right` template to be empty (this is the template where the logo goes in the `default` theme). The following example shows this redefinition (you might need to adjust the lengths in the `\raisebox` to suit your needs):

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\logo{\includegraphics[width=.5cm,keepaspectratio]{tux}}

\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{logo-frame number}
{
  \rlap{\raisebox{-1.75ex}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[\paperwidth]{\insertlogo}}}%
  \hfill%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}%
  \insertframenumber\,/\,  \inserttotalframenumber\kern1em\vskip2pt%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{Hello world}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

If all you want to do is to flush the logo to the left, all you have to do is to get ride of your \makebox:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\logo{\includegraphics[width=.5cm,keepaspectratio]{tux}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{Hello world}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I wish to put the logo at top right corner, is it possible?

Comment: @lucky1928 Sure it's possible. Feel free to open a fresh new question (your request is not directly related to the issue discussed here). Don't forget to mention the theme(s) used and the exact desired position for the logo.

Comment: Thanks, create a new topic [put logo on top right corner in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228055/put-logo-on-top-right-corner-in-beamer)

Answer (score 3):

By default `\makebox` has center alignment. So you have to use

```
\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{....}
```

to flush things to the right. Another simpler way is this:

```
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{logo}{logo.png}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}\quad}
```

I have added `\quad to push the image little to the left so as to align with the page number.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
%\logo{\makebox[\paperwidth][r]{\includegraphics[width=.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}\quad}}
\pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{logo}{logo.png}
\logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}\quad}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{Hello world}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To put logo at any place you wish, we can use pgf as below:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usepackage{pgf}  
\logo{\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0,7)}{\pgfbox[right,base]{\includegraphics[width=1.6cm]{logo.png}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]{Hello world}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1 Test line with loooooooooooooooooooooong text to cross the image 
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Still few questions:

- pgf coordinate seems strange, (0,7) now located at top right corner.
- Wish to use a page height variable to replace 7, but still not got it.

Comment: That's what I want.

Comment: Please, don't use answers to ask new questions. Use a fresh new proper question for this.

Comment: Sorry about that, but I don't want new question being duplicated so just ask it here!it actually current question's solution but still need some improve I think.

Comment: @Beatlej I don't think your new question will be a duplicate; in any case, asking new questions in an answer is not an accepted or encouraged practice around here; furthermore, not many people will see your question and it will barely receive any attention. I'd advise you to open a new question.