# put logo on top right corner in beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to put logo at top right corner in beamer, maybe just align with the title line but should not depended on title bar exist or not :-).

For reference,[another topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227892/align-logo-with-pagenumber-in-beamer) is to put logo at the bottom line.

Current code as below:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\logo{\makebox[1\paperwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{Hello world}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Current output is:

[image]

Comment: I wish it appear at every slide, so maybe it's different topic.

Comment: A better duplicate would then be given by: [How do I add an image in the upper, left-hand corner using TikZ and `graphicx`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38751/5764); it shouldn't matter whether you're using [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) or not.

Answer (score 23):

Put it any where you like with `eso-pic`

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\newcommand\AtPagemyUpperLeft[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
\put(\LenToUnit{0.9\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0.9\paperheight}){#1}}}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{
  \AtPagemyUpperLeft{{\includegraphics[width=.5cm,keepaspectratio]{logo.png}}}
}%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[c]{Hello world}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Adjust `\LenToUnit{0.9\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0.9\paperheight}` in

```
\newcommand\AtPagemyUpperLeft[1]{\AtPageLowerLeft{%
\put(\LenToUnit{0.9\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{0.9\paperheight}){#1}}}
```

as you wish.